# Get an Input value using jQuery after a few milliseconds

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I want to get the value of an input field and send an ajax request. If I use keyup or keypress or change, the value is available instantly and request is sent. I want to wait for the user e.g. for 1 or 2 seconds so that he types whole word and then send an ajax request. 
My code is like this to get the vlaue. Thanks.

```
    var timeout = window.setTimeout(function() {
        $('input#search').keyup(function() {
            var key = $("#search").val();
            console.log(key);
        });

    }, 1000);
    clearTimeout(timeout);
```

Comment: This is not the best approach if you're hoping to deliver a positive user experience.  You can never be sure that the user is done typing just because you have waited an arbitrary number of seconds.  Some people type awfully slow.  You should consider either a button next to the form which triggers the ajax request, or listen for the "enter" key in the text field and make the request then.

Comment: Thank you for your comment.I've added a submit button but I also want to trigger an ajax request when user inputs something. I just want to trigger ajax request after 1 or 2 seconds.

Comment: @VCode: google search autocomplete works without a button

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to use a timer and then use clearTimeout it to reset it as the user types. This code will do what you want and here's a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wsw2qgz6/).

```
var Timer;

function Start() {

    $('#TheInput').keyup(function () {

        clearTimeout(Timer);
        Timer = setTimeout(SendRequest, 1000);
    });
}


function SendRequest() {

    var key = $("#TheInput").val();    
    alert(key);
}

$(Start);
```

Comment: I didnt realize you could call a function like `$(Start);`.  Is there any benefit to doing this rather than Start();?

Comment: Thank you @frenchie, this is exactly what I was asking for.

Comment: @DelightedD0D: writing $(Start) is shorthand for writing $(document).ready(Start)

Comment: Thats perfect, just what i needed!

Answer (score 3):

Every time you call the function, you should clear the timeout and set a new one, try this:

```
(function () {
   var timeout = {};
   var update = function () {
     clearTimeout(timeout);
     timeout = setTimeout(function () {
       var key = $('#search').val();
       console.log(key);
     }, 1000);
   };

   $('input#search').keyup(update);
   $('input#search').change(update);
 }());
```